# C++ Хочу модернизировать программку с вводом функцией "random"

Tags: c++

**Здравствуйте, Уважаемые знатоки!  мне 67 лет, проучился на курсах "foundation". Xотел бы получить более глубокие познания в этой области науки.**
Имею программу :

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void selectionSort (int arr[],int arrSize){
int min_idx;
int i=0;
for(int i =0; i<arrSize-1;i++)
{
 min_idx = i;
for(int j =i+1; j < arrSize; j++)
 if(arr[j]<arr[min_idx])
 min_idx = j;
 std::swap(arr[i],arr[min_idx]);
}

}
void printArray(int arr[],int arrSize){
for(int i =0; i<arrSize;i++){

 std::cout << arr[i]<< " ";
}

}
int main()
{
constexpr int arrSize=10;
int arr[arrSize] {2,1,18,14,28,17,99,77,88,100};
selectionSort(arr,arrSize);
printArray(arr,arrSize);
return 0;
}
```

**хотел чуть переделать вводя функцию "random" и вводить цифры каждый раз случайные и получить правильно от сортированные**

```
srand(time(NULL));
 int arrSize = 10;
 int ratings[arrSize];
 for(int i =0; i<arrSize; i++)
 {
     ratings[i] = rand()%10; 
 }
```

**совместить не получается помогите пожалуйста, как можно подробнее**

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно... Вы хотите просто создать массив со случайными данными? Типа [этого](https://ideone.com/i9d7Vp):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void selectionSort (int arr[],int arrSize)
{
    int min_idx;
    for(int i =0; i<arrSize-1;i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        for(int j =i+1; j < arrSize; j++)
            if(arr[j]<arr[min_idx])
                min_idx = j;
        std::swap(arr[i],arr[min_idx]);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[],int arrSize)
{
    for(int i =0; i<arrSize;i++){

        std::cout << arr[i]<< " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    constexpr int arrSize=10;
    int ratings[arrSize];
    for(int i =0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        ratings[i] = rand()%10;
    }
    selectionSort(ratings ,arrSize);
    printArray(ratings, arrSize);
}
```

Или вы хотите именно функцию, создающую массив? тогда встречные вопросы — нужен именно массив, или можно (раз у нас С++) `vector`? Если именно массив — то вы уже в курсе о динамическом выделении памяти через `new`?